# Have Android Options Menu wait until return from Web Request

Tags: android, json

I am calling an endpoint to pull in JSON. I want the activity to wait to set up the options menu because I want a star icon to appear full if a key-value returns true from the web service and vice versa. 
I've tried programming this with onPrepareOptionsMenu() but because the response is on a separate thread it loads the default of the toggle icons.

And pointers would be helpful!

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    if(isFavorite){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.action_non_favorite);
        menu.add(101, R.id.action_favorite, 0, "true");
    }else{
        menu.removeItem(R.id.action_favorite);
        menu.add(101, R.id.action_non_favorite, 0, "false");
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and here is the request:

```
private void sendDetailRequest(String urlRequest, final Person contact) {
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlRequest, null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String jsonString = response.toString();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Person.PersonDetail personDetail = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Person.PersonDetail.class);
            contact.setContactDetails(personDetail);
            isFavorite = personDetail.favorite;

            //prepareOptionsMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
            buildPage(contact);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(contactDetails.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(objectRequest1);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a star icon to appear full if a key-value returns true from the web service and vice versa

Step #1: Create the menu normally. However, have `android:visible="false"` on the `<item>` for the star.

Step #2: In `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, after using the `MenuInflater` to inflate the menu, [call `findItem()` on the `Menu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int)), passing in the ID of your star item. Hold onto that `MenuItem` in a field of your activity or fragment.

Step #3: When your Web service call completes, back on the main application thread, if needed, [call `setVisible(true)` on the `MenuItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean)), to make the star visible to the user.

IOW, do not try to delay creation of the action bar items, as that will not work well. Instead, make the items visible and invisible as needed.

Comment: Edit: Wait! I figured it out, had an exception that i wasnt catching from another part of the code. It works like a charm! 
----
Thanks for the response. I think im close...it's entering into the conditional if/else depending on the value of the boolean, however, when it is true, the settings ellipses has the word true, and no star. When it's false, works just fine.